# Namespace for Referenced DLL is Available in Controllers/Models, Not in Views

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2019

I have an MVC project that makes reference to a custom DLL in another project. The DLL is called "Web" and has the classes that I need in "Models".

I have added the DLL as a reference in the project where it is needed, and in the controllers and the models of the project, it is available. I can use the line:

```
using Web.Models.Base;
```

And

```
using Web.Models.AppToolKit
```

And all the objects in those classes are available.

However in the views, in that same project, the Web namespace is not available at all. I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Web' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And when I use the model I created in the project in the view, which inherits from the reference DLL and compiles with no problem, I get the error:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'BasicNetPageModel' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Even though that DLL is referenced, and is working in both the models and the controllers for the same project.

I am using VS 2019. I have tried removing/re-adding the reference and cleaning/rebuilding many times.

I have tried adding:

```
<add namespace="TASWeb.Models.Base"/>
```

in the web.config.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the error is shown in Error List window and Editor? Probably the platform built of your dll is different to your project.

Comment: Did you try something like @using Web.Models.Base in the view?

Comment: @Adleri Ya it shows in both. I checked both projects and they are .Net 4.6.1 with target platform of x64.

Comment: @DickBos I did yes and it says " name 'Web' could not be found".

Comment: Have you checked if it isnt a profiling issue

Comment: @Adlert not sure what you mean by profiling issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was a second DLL, which was referenced from within the first DLL.

The project for that one was set to x86. I set it to ANY CPU, recompiled, then recompiled the first DLL, then the project in question was able to recognize the namespace.